# How to install LamsTeX on TeX Live (Linux)?

Tags: installing

[LamsTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/lamstex) macro package is on CTAN but is not installed in my TeX Live.  How can I install it?  Where should I put the files?

Note that, in addition, LamsTeX uses the [index-processor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lamstex-index) and [dvipaste](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dvipaste) programs.  So they should also be installed.

Comment: You seem to be really fond of software archaeology.

Comment: @egreg I'm just looking for a format better than LaTeX.  Old does not mean worse :)

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure LamsTeX is not better than LaTeX. And it's much less documented; there's plenty of free documentation for LaTeX, none for LamsTeX, unless you're able to buy the book from TeXplorators Co. (I believe the company doesn't exist any more). Also, you'll have to compile the two auxiliary programs yourself.

Comment: @egreg Have you tried it?  If so, then can you say me why you think it is not better than LaTeX?  What aspects of it make it worse than LaTeX? (BTW, compiling two C source code is not a problem at all).

Comment: As far as I know, LamsTeX adds some bells and whistles to AMSTeX, in particular cross references. But its nonfree status and the lack of documentation makes it unusable. It has been dead and undeveloped for twenty years. All you can do with it can be done with LaTeX; the converse is definitely false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LamsTeX package is freely available on CTAN, but the user's manual was distributed for a charge by TeXplorators Corporations Inc.; as far as I can see, the company is not active any more. They developed and distributed also the MathTime font family, now maintained and sold by PCTeX Inc.

The package has been undeveloped for more than twenty years: the last release on CTAN is dated September 1991 and there's no way to obtain the manual. Only the “wizards manual” is available, not the user's manual.

LamsTeX is an extension of AMSTeX, providing some more tools: cross references, indexing and diagrams. All that can be done with LamsTeX can be done with LaTeX; the converse is, of course, false. For instance, language and input encoding support is completely inexistent.

How to install it? Easy. I assume a “vanilla TeX Live”; with other distributions of TeX Live, change `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` by what's output when the shell command

```
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

is issued.

Create the directories

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/lamstex
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/lamstex
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/lamstex
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/lamstex
```

In the first copy the files in the `input` directory (I'm referring to the tree structure of the distribution on CTAN); in the second the contents of the `doc` directory, in the third the contents of the `mf` directory and in the fourth the contents of the `tfm` directory.

Run, with superuser privileges,

```
mktexlsr
```

and you'll be ready to use LamsTeX. The indexing program and `dvipaste` should be compiled separately.